# Need to put a HTTPS server/proxy between internal server and outside world

Tags: linux, windows, security, reverse-proxy

I have an internal device that I need to have "proxied" to the outside world. What would be the best way to set this up? Flow is as below:

Internal Device<->Proxy<->Router<->Outside world. The router is a Cisco IOS device performing NAT. The Internal device is a device that I do not want to have direct access to the outside world (also, its HTTPS certificate is not valid, as it is a non-CA certificate, your typical self-signed). The proxy to the outside would have a valid CA certificate.

The Internal Device cannot be directly connected to the Internet due to security policies.

I hope this makes sense, and that I'm not oversimplifying it (or overthinking it).

Comment: That's the way everyone else does it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a http reverse proxy.